# How to skip a WizardStep in WizarDroid

Tags: android, wizard

I use WizarDroid and I intend to skip a step if certain conditions are met.

I have the following flow:

```
flow = new WizardFlow.Builder()
      .setActivity(this)                      //First, set the hosting activity for the wizard
      .setContainerId(R.id.step_container)    //then set the layout container for the steps.
      .addStep(WStep1.class)                   //Add your steps in the order you want them
      .addStep(WStep2.class)                  //to appear and eventually call create()
      .addStep(WStep3.class)                 //to create the wizard flow.
      .create();
```

I intend to skip WStep2, if a variable is set.

Based on its tutorial, I only can disable to advance to the next step until I set it so: [Controlling wizard flow dynamically](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid/wiki/Controlling-wizard-flow-dynamically)

How can I tell the wizard that the next step can be skipped?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like WizarDroid doesn't provide the ability to remove a step from the WizardFlow.

But, you can check that variable you mention in `WStep2`, and just call `goNext()`. This will work for sure.

If you'd like to try another way, you could also use (although I can't assure it would work):

```
setStepCompleted(1, true) //setStepCompleted(int stepPosition, boolean stepCompleted)
```

edit: seeing that you also want to go backwards in the wizard, you'll have to split the wizard.

I mean, if you want to skip WStep3 in certain circumstances:

in you MainActivity.class

```
flow1 = new WizardFlow.Builder()
      .setActivity(this)
      .setContainerId(R.id.step_container)
      .addStep(WStep1.class)
      .addStep(WStep2.class)
      .create();
```

in WStep2.class

```
if (skipWStep3()){
    flow2 = new WizardFlow.Builder()
              .setActivity(this)
              .setContainerId(R.id.step_container)
              .addStep(WStep4.class)
              .addStep(WStep5.class)
          .create();
}
else {
    flow2 = new WizardFlow.Builder()
              .setActivity(this)
              .setContainerId(R.id.step_container)
              .addStep(WStep3.class)
              .addStep(WStep4.class)
              .addStep(WStep5.class)
          .create();
}
```

Comment: In which method should I call goNext? I tried to call 'done' in 'onCreate' and it seemed to skip it, but when I use the Back button, it goes back to the 'hidden' page.

Comment: So you want to go forward and backward... Using WizarDroid, looks like you take a different approach. I'll just edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Skipping a step is not supported by default in BasicWizardLayout. You'd have to either sub-class it and use the API method Wizard#setCurrentStep, or write your own wizard layout class by sub-classing WizardFragment as explained [here](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid/wiki/Creating-Custom-Wizard-Layout).

> void org.codepond.wizardroid.Wizard.setCurrentStep    (   int 
>     stepPosition    )
>
> Sets the current step of the wizard
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> stepPosition the position of the step within the WizardFlow
> ```